# Using $e^{iz^2}$ vs. $e^{-z^2}$ to calculate Fresnel Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, fresnel-integrals

I have been doing some research and found out that the most used function to contour integrate when it comes to fresnel integrals is $e^{iz^2}$ on the boundary of $|z| \leq R$ and $0 \leq \arg(z) \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$. For this one I understand the splitting process into $\cos$ and $\sin$ thanks to $e^{iz}$ identity.

Recently, I also found out that, sometimes, it is used the function $e^{-z^2}$ on the same contour, achieving the same result for both integrals of $\cos(x^2)$ and $\sin(x^2)$

My question is: which of those 2 functions simplify the proof and calculations? How can you use the exponential identity with the last one if there is no $i$ in its exponent?

thanks in advance

Comment: $z$ is a complex number along the contour in both cases, so multiplication by $i$ isn't really doing much anyhow that the $-1$ isn't, merely helping with convergence

Comment: @SebastianGiraldoGomez Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can

Comment: @sebastiangiraldogomez Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question, "How can you use the exponential identity with the last one if there is no $i$ in its exponent?," we proceed as follows.

Let $C_R$ denote the closed contour comprised of $(1)$ the straight line segment from $0$ to $R$, $(2)$ the circular arc from $R$ to $Re^{i\pi/4}$, and $(3)$ the straight line segment from $Re^{i\pi/4}$ to $0$.

Inasmuch as $e^{-z^2}$ is analytic, Cauchy's integral theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
0&=\oint_{C_R} e^{-z^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_0^R e^{-x^2}\,dx +\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2 e^{i2\phi}}\,ie^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_{R}^0e^{-t^2 e^{-i\pi/2}}e^{-i\pi/4}\,dt\\\\&=\int_0^R e^{-x^2}\,dx-e^{-i\pi/4}\int_0^R e^{it^2}\,dt +\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2 e^{i2\phi}}\,ie^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag1
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$, the thrid integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ vanishes and we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{it^2}\,dt&=e^{i\pi/4}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{4}(1+i)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: (+1) your solutions look always very simple; that takes some skill. By the way, I think I found a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4577211/121671) to a previous posting you were working on. I hope the writing is a s clear as yours.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you!  Much appreciated.  I had a look at your solution to the other problem and it looked good.

Comment: @SebastianGiraldoGomez Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can

Comment: @MarkViola Actually, your answer was enlightening. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SebastianGiraldoGomez Pleased to hear and you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @SebastianGiraldoGomez And feel free to up vote and accept an answer that you found useful as you see fit. ;-)